# How to use Intel N2800 / GMA 3650 in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, graphics, intel

So my friends start buying these N2600/2800 netbooks. In 12.04 KDE kind of works. But now I tried to install 12.10 on N2800. Installation went fine but it won't boot and there are no `cedarview-*` packages in repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 12.10 is not and will not be supported :(

http://communities.intel.com/message/160444#160444